# JSON throwing java.lang.StackOverflowError in select all

Tags: java, json, hibernate, stack-overflow

**Hello, I am writing to you with a question**

Well, I have java ee entity *MestechnologyGroup*, which is connected to *MesTechnology*. I am using JPA and hibernate and when I want to extract from the json database with data (select all)
the browser throws me

**java.lang.StackOverflowError**

Here is MestechnologyGroup  Entity

```
package pl.test.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
public class Mestechnologygroup {
    private Integer idTechnologyGroup;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Integer number;
    private Collection<Mestechnology> mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idTechnologyGroup")
    public Integer getIdTechnologyGroup() {
        return idTechnologyGroup;
    }

    public void setIdTechnologyGroup(Integer idTechnologyGroup) {
        this.idTechnologyGroup = idTechnologyGroup;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Number")
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Mestechnologygroup that = (Mestechnologygroup) o;

        if (idTechnologyGroup != null ? !idTechnologyGroup.equals(that.idTechnologyGroup) : that.idTechnologyGroup != null)
            return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;
        if (number != null ? !number.equals(that.number) : that.number != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = idTechnologyGroup != null ? idTechnologyGroup.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (number != null ? number.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup")
    public Collection<Mestechnology> getMestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup() {
        return mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup;
    }

    public void setMestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup(Collection<Mestechnology> mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup) {
        this.mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup = mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup;
    }
```

}

And *MesTechnology* Entity

```
    package pl.test.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
public class Mestechnology {
    private Integer idTechnology;
    private Integer number;
    private String name;
    private Boolean state;
    private Collection<Mesattachmenttechnology> mesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology;
    private Collection<Mesoperation> mesoperationsByIdTechnology;
    private Mestechnologygroup mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idTechnology")
    public Integer getIdTechnology() {
        return idTechnology;
    }

    public void setIdTechnology(Integer idTechnology) {
        this.idTechnology = idTechnology;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "number")
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "state")
    public Boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(Boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Mestechnology that = (Mestechnology) o;

        if (idTechnology != null ? !idTechnology.equals(that.idTechnology) : that.idTechnology != null) return false;
        if (number != null ? !number.equals(that.number) : that.number != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (state != null ? !state.equals(that.state) : that.state != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = idTechnology != null ? idTechnology.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (number != null ? number.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (state != null ? state.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mestechnologyByIdTechnology")
    public Collection<Mesattachmenttechnology> getMesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology() {
        return mesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology;
    }

    public void setMesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology(Collection<Mesattachmenttechnology> mesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology) {
        this.mesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology = mesattachmenttechnologiesByIdTechnology;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mestechnologyByIdTechnology")
    public Collection<Mesoperation> getMesoperationsByIdTechnology() {
        return mesoperationsByIdTechnology;
    }

    public void setMesoperationsByIdTechnology(Collection<Mesoperation> mesoperationsByIdTechnology) {
        this.mesoperationsByIdTechnology = mesoperationsByIdTechnology;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTechnologyGroup", referencedColumnName = "idTechnologyGroup", nullable = false)
    public Mestechnologygroup getMestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup() {
        return mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup;
    }

    public void setMestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup(Mestechnologygroup mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup) {
        this.mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup = mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup;
    }
}
```

*TechnologyGroupRepositorum*

```
package pl.test.repo;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import pl.test.model.Mestechnologygroup;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS;

@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
public class TechnologyGroupRepo {

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    public List<Object[]> findById(@NotNull Integer id) {
        TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery("select t.name, t.number, t.description from Mestechnologygroup t where t.idTechnologyGroup =:id" , Object[].class)
                .setParameter("id",id);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Mestechnologygroup> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Mestechnologygroup> query = em.createQuery("from Mestechnologygroup", Mestechnologygroup.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }


//dodać dodawanie i deletowanie
```

}

*TechnologyGroupEndpoint*

```
package pl.test.rest;


import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import pl.test.model.Mestechnologygroup;
import pl.test.model.Mesusers;
import pl.test.repo.TechnologyGroupRepo;
import pl.test.repo.UserRepo;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import java.util.List;

import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED;
import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
@Api("technologygorup")
@Path("/tg")
public class TechnologyGroupEndpoint{

    @Inject
    private TechnologyGroupRepo technologyGroupRepo;


    @GET
    @Path("/{id : \\d+}")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTechnologyGroup(@PathParam("id")  Integer id) {
        Object[] mestechnologygroup = technologyGroupRepo.findById(id).toArray();

        if (mestechnologygroup == null)
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();

        return Response.ok(mestechnologygroup).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTechnologyGroups() {
        List<Mestechnologygroup> mestechnologygroups=technologyGroupRepo.findAll();

        if (mestechnologygroups.size() == 0)
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();

        return Response.ok(mestechnologygroups).build();
    }


}
```

server loogs

```
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializeItem(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:52)
]]
```

Error Thrown by Browser
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7aKQ.png)
i would appreciate any help

Comment: You mean JSON serialisation (presuming that this org.eclipse.yasson is that ... JAXB and JSON) has a stack overflow, not JPA

Comment: Yes my bad, soory

Comment: @BillyFrost any ideas why its not woorking

Comment: There are literally hundreds of posts on this site about JSON and stack overflow, and the majority involve `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: I added @JsonIgnore and that isnt works :/

Comment: I wrote a long and precise answer, only to notice that you're not using Jackson for serialization, so it won't work. `@JsonIgnore` is a Jackson annotation. You need `@JsonbTransient` in the `Mestechnologygroup` class on the `mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MestechnologyGroup has a collection of MesTechnology which has a back reference to the MestechnologyGroup. When serializing it'll serialize the MestechnologyGroup where it finds a MesTechnology to serialize, where it finds the MestechnologyGroup again ... stack overflow.

Add @JsonbTransient on the @ManyToOne to stop it.

```
@JsonbTransient
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idTechnologyGroup", referencedColumnName = "idTechnologyGroup", nullable = false)
public Mestechnologygroup getMestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup() {
    return mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup;
}
```

You have @OneToMany from Mestechnology to both Mesattachmenttechnology and Mesoperation. You'll need to Json ignore the @ManyToOne side in those entities too.

Comment: Still stackOverflow

Comment: updated answer, you need to keep going down all the entities you have one to many relationships with.

Comment: Anywhere you have a recursion. many 2 one in JPA is a common way of adding them.

Comment: You could try @Transient instead of JsonIgnore. Maybe yasson doesn't respect the JsonIgnore.

Comment: Or even @JsonbTransient. I've not used yasson, but it looks like that's what JSON-B uses, I'm more familiar with Jackson which uses JsonIgnore.

Comment: @Transient  sollved problem

Comment: Remember in stack trace the error is `org.eclipse.yasson.internal` for this reason the correct annotation is `@JsonbTransient` (Yasson standard [library] (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson)). @JsonIgnore annotation is for Jackson and don't apply in this case. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348184/4156219

Comment: @pcoates Life saver.