# Stakover flow error with Jackson applied on JPA Entities to generate JSON

Tags: java, json, jpa-2.0, one-to-many, yasson

I have a `JPA` code with `OneToMany` relationship. A `Customer` has a list of `Item` to check out. However, the code continue to generate `StackOverflowError`.

Once, I had resolved this one by applying `@JsonIgnore` while fetching the `List<Item>` from Customer entity. But even that does not seem to work anymore.

In `Customer` class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Item> items;
```

In `Item` class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
```

And `CustomerRest` class:

```
@Path("customers")
public class CustomerRest {

    @Inject
    NewSessionBean newSessionBean;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        return newSessionBean.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

Method `newSessionBean.getCustomers()`:

```
public List<Customer> getCustomers(){
    TypedQuery<Customer> q= em.createQuery("select c from Customer c", Customer.class);

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

I expect a nicely formatted JSON message but there is no sign of this. All I get is the `java.lang.StackOverflowError` on the browser and the Server log generates the following:

```
Generating incomplete JSON|#]
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.lang.StackOverflowError    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DefaultSerializers.findByCondition(DefaultSerializers.java:130)
```

Comment: You need to take a look at: `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations. Read: [Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion). See also: [Searching proper way to convert my two-way linkage between objects to JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853178/searching-proper-way-to-convert-my-two-way-linkage-between-objects-to-json-forma), [Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383889/jackson-hibernate-meta-get-methods-and-serialization)

Comment: Thanks. But, I did try JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference - in vain.

Comment: You're not using Jackson to serialize your objects to JSON. So using Jackson annotations won't fix anything. Read your stacktrace: `at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DefaultSerializers.findByCondition(DefaultSerializers.java:130)`. You're using yasson, not Jackson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you use [Yasson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson) project not [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). In that case you should use `@JsonbTransient` annotation. See [documentation](http://json-b.net/docs/user-guide.html#ignoring-properties):

> By default, `JSONB` ignores properties with a non public access. All
>   public properties - either public fields or non public fields with
>   public getters are serialized into `JSON` text.
>
> Excluding properties can be done with a `@JsonbTransient` annotation.
>   Class properties annotated with `@JsonbTransient` annotation are ignored
>   by `JSON Binding` engine. The behavior is different depending on where
>   `@JsonbTransient` annotation is placed.

See also:

- [Circular reference issue with JSON-B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087178/circular-reference-issue-with-json-b)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, that trick works indeed. Many Thanks!!